# Redis search not found with composed label

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to query by secondary index in my redis.

When  I query the redis with a single label it works, for example:

```
FT.SEARCH LiveRooms-idx "@numUsers:[100 200]"
```

But when I query with a composed label like this:

```
FT.SEARCH LiveRooms-idx "@profile.profileName:'Panticosa, Aragón (España)"
```

I receive an error: `"Syntax error at offset 9 near profileName"`

The composed label see like this:
[Redis labels schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNQSN.png)

And the idx is like this:

```
Field<String> activityType = Field.text("profile.activityType").build();
            Field<String> profileId = Field.text("profileId").sortable(true).build();
            Field<String> profileName = Field.text("profile.profileName").build();
            Field<String> creatorName = Field.text("creatorName").sortable(true).build();
            Field<String> totalDistance = Field.numeric("profile.totalDistance").build();
            Field<String> totalGain = Field.numeric("profile.totalGain").build();
            Field<String> maxSlope = Field.numeric("profile.maxSlope").build();
            Field<String> numUsers = Field.numeric("numUsers").sortable(true).build();
            Field<String> a = Field.numeric("profile.views.[0]").sortable(true).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape `.`

`"@profile\.profileName:'Panticosa, Aragón (España)"`

Comment: I got  the same error

Comment: Was it in the same place? I think the `'` needs escaped as well.

Comment: Or it needs closing partner on the other side.

Comment: @GuyRoyse sorry, the search its like this : "@profile\.profileName:Panticosa, Aragón (España)" without the '

Comment: @SergioAlcalde you can use `_` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Ariel I cant, because its a object inside another object in java

Comment: @SergioAlcalde you can add an attribute with a legal name.  `profile.totalDistance as profileDistance`. Then use profileDistance in the query.

Comment: @Ariel Okai, u have some link o how i can do this when i save in redis? some anotation???

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/escaping/